# My Toshiba Satellite C55-B5319 fans will not turn on; how do I make them work?

Tags: overheating, fan, temperature, fancontrol

The system hasn't shut down automatically due to overheating yet, but the HDD will reach temperatures of 102 degrees Fahrenheit as far as I know. So, how do I make the fans turn on, or is the HDD supposed to get that hot?

Also I think the fans did turn on when I was running Windows 10, furthermore they're probably not broken because the laptop is only about 3 months old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A temperature of 102 Fahrenheit is perfectly normal for a laptop HDD. Toshiba HDDs can operate up to 55 Celcius = 131 Fahrenheit.

The fan in a laptop is designed to cool the heatsink on the processor and video chip and will have little effect on the temperature of the HDD.

If the fans came on when you were running Windows 10 but not Ubuntu it is a measure of how much more efficent Ubuntu is as an operating system.